# Saving Triangle for Redrawing C#

Tags: c#, graphics

I'd like to Save all points need for drawing the rectangle into a list to be able to draw another triangle and retaining the previous one. I did this on other shapes such as Rectangle & etc. by saving them in

```
List< Rectangle > _rect = new List< Rectangle >
```

and iterating through them using

```
foreach(Rects rect in _rect)
```

What to do when it comes to triangle?

```
    public PointF[] tPoints { get; set; }

    public void DrawTriangle(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        tPoints = new PointF[3];
        float angle = 0;
        tPoints[0].X = x;
        tPoints[0].Y = y;
        tPoints[1].X = (float)(x + width * Math.Cos(angle));
        tPoints[1].Y = (float)(y + width * Math.Sin(angle));
        tPoints[2].X = (float)(x + width * Math.Cos(angle - Math.PI / 3));
        tPoints[2].Y = (float)(y + width * Math.Sin(angle - Math.PI / 3));

        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(new Pen(color, strokeThickness), tPoints);
    }
```

Comment: Just use another list with triangles instead of rectangles? Can you show some code that you want to extend, and explain more clearly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Added codes in my post.

Comment: In computer science, "code" is used as a mass noun, specifying the collection of instructions in a specific arrangement as a whole and in no specific quantity. Whether it's one line of code or ten pages, it is still referred to as code, not codes. in short, its "here is my *code*" not "here is my codes" just for future reference

Comment: _All your codes belongs to us_

Comment: @TaW made my afternoon, yes its been slow

Comment: Still, my question is that, using the code I wrote, how do I retain the previous triangle and draw another?

Comment: You nee to keep them __all__ in a list and draw __each__ in the Paint event. - With a celver shape class you can simply write: `foreach (Shape shape in shapes) shape.Draw(e.Graphics);`

Comment: @TaW I mean just for the triangle, because I can retain my Rectangle, Square, Circle and Ellipse. I just don't know how to do it with triangles. But thanks for the suggeston :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create such a data type yourself!

```
struct Triangle {
    // all your need for a triangle is three points, isn't it?
    public Point PointA { get; }
    public Point PointB { get; }
    public Point PointC { get; }

    public Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
        PointA = a;
        PointB = b;
        PointC = c;
    }
}
```

And then you can create a list of it:

```
var triangles = new List<Triangles>();
```

Comment: Got the idea, thanks. You don't need and exclamatory.

Comment: Better yet: Create a class that knows how to draw itself. And with which color. And pen style.. And later move on to an interface IDrawable..

Comment: @TaW I guess you could do that, but I prefer to isolate the drawing logic from the model classes.

Comment: To each his own. It is still more of an art than science.. I prefer to keep the responsibility to know what to do with th data with the classes and not having to make that distinction at the upprt ('board/canvas') level..